# reduced density matrix of multiparticle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

Let the state of a composite system is $|\psi_{i}\rangle$ then the density matrix is defined as, $\rho=\sum P_{i}|\psi_{i}\rangle\langle\psi_{i}|$

Consider a composite system of two particles and its state is described by the density matrix $\rho^{AB}$, the state of the subsystem $A$ is $\rho^{A}=Tr_{B}(\rho^{AB})$.

where $Tr_{B}(.)$ is the partial trace over subsystem $B$.

If we have N number of particles with the density operator $\rho$, what does it mean to take the trace over the particles 2 to N ?, i.e, 
$$
Tr_{2,..,N}(\rho)=Tr_{2}(Tr_{3}(....Tr_{N}(\rho))) 
$$
and what is its eigenvalue ?

`Note:`Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You ask many very similar questions in the last 1-2 days ...  In any case, the trace of particles 2...N is the same as in a bipartite system AB, just that B now denotes the particles 2...N together.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanx. So $\rho^{1}=Tr_{2,..,N}(\rho)$ describes the state of the one particle system in the N particle composite system. Is that correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "state of the one-particle system".  It describes the state of particle 1 (or, in case of indistinguishable particles, of one particle).  I'm not sure what "system" refers to here.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It is an N particle bosonic system. Its is defined that if one finds the eigenvalue $n$ of $\rho^{1}=Tr_{2,..,N}(\rho)$ which is of the order of the total number of particles $N$ is the system, then $n$ particles are said to be condensed. I am having trouble understanding this statement based on the above definition of $\rho^{1}$. ?